# Type private methods in ext Docs

Tags: extjs

a co-worker gave me the information that the private methods of ext are for Sencha's exclusive use and I would like to know if this is true. And if not, I would like to know why he is private.

Here is a image about what I'm talking about.

[private methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaEUE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK private methods can be changed in the next releases of Sencha products. Public methods are stabler and used to be "deprecated" for several versions. It means, in case of upgrade of framework, you will have to change/rewrite more code.
So nobody can forbid you to change the code in your project but better to avoid it.